# create a list from dictionary based on a specific Key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

If you have a list of dictionaries:

How to do you filter the names of all the female or male in a list?

I was trying as below

```
example = [
{'name':'Jane','gender':'female'},
{'name':'Ben','gender':'male'},
{'name':'Kate','gender':'female'},
{'name':'James','gender':'male'},
{'name':'Lilly','gender':'female'},
{'name':'Sam','gender':'male'},
{'name':'Grace','gender':'female'},
{'name':'Dan','gender':'male'}
]

for dictionary in example:
    dictfilt = lambda x, y: dict([(i, x[i]) for i in x if i in set(y)])
    wanted_keys = ("name", "gender")
    result = dictfilt(dictionary, wanted_keys)
    print(result)

#### The output will give a tuple of the name and the gender ####

for item in result.items():
    print(item)
    for key, value in result.items():
        if value == 'one_day':
            print(key)
```

but it is far from what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works for you:

```
my_list = [
    {"name": "Jane", "gender": "female"},
    {"name": "Ben", "gender": "male"},
    {"name": "Kate", "gender": "female"},
    {"name": "James", "gender": "male"},
    {"name": "Lilly", "gender": "female"},
    {"name": "Sam", "gender": "male"},
    {"name": "Grace", "gender": "female"},
    {"name": "Dan", "gender": "male"},
]
m=[]
f=[]
for i in my_list:
    if i["gender"]=="male":
        m.append(i["name"])
    else:
        f.append(i["name"])
print(f"Male:\n{m}\nFemale:\n{f}")
```

New code:

```
my_list =[{'id': '*1', 'name': 'admin', 'password': '1234', 'profile': 'default', 'uptime': '1h3m49s', 'bytes-in': '769490', 'bytes-out': '9543516', 'packets-in': '4389', 'packets-out': '7383', 'dynamic': 'false', 'disabled': 'false'}, {'id': '*2', 'server': 'hotspot1', 'name': 'ARTRbD0W', 'password': 'ARTRbD0W', 'profile': '1hour', 'limit-uptime': '1h', 'uptime': '0s', 'bytes-in': '0', 'bytes-out': '0', 'packets-in': '0', 'packets-out': '0', 'dynamic': 'false', 'disabled': 'false', 'comment': '1 Hour : "30"'}]
names=[]
for i in my_list:
    if "profile" in i:
        if i["profile"]=="1hour":
            names.append(i["name"])
print(f"Names:\n{names}")
```

Result:

```
Names:
['ARTRbD0W']
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqATJ.png)

Comment: if i["profile"] == "1hour":
KeyError: 'profile'                                                                                                                                           Why am I getting this error

Comment: Can you please share your code? Do you have a key named "profile" in your dictionary?

Comment: my exact code is: [{'id': '*1', 'name': 'admin', 'password': '1234', 'profile': 'default', 'uptime': '1h3m49s', 'bytes-in': '769490', 'bytes-out': '9543516', 'packets-in': '4389', 'packets-out': '7383', 'dynamic': 'false', 'disabled': 'false'}, {'id': '*2', 'server': 'hotspot1', 'name': 'ARTRbD0W', 'password': 'ARTRbD0W', 'profile': '1hour', 'limit-uptime': '1h', 'uptime': '0s', 'bytes-in': '0', 'bytes-out': '0', 'packets-in': '0', 'packets-out': '0', 'dynamic': 'false', 'disabled': 'false', 'comment': '1 Hour : "30"'}]

Comment: So I want to create a list of usernames based on the profile, if the profile says 1hour, I get all the names

Comment: Check your code again please.

Comment: my_list =[{'id': '*1', 'name': 'admin', 'password': '1234', 'profile': 'default', 'uptime': '1h3m49s', 'bytes-in': '769490', 'bytes-out': '9543516', 'packets-in': '4389', 'packets-out': '7383', 'dynamic': 'false', 'disabled': 'false'}, {'id': '*2', 'server': 'hotspot1', 'name': 'ARTRbD0W', 'password': 'ARTRbD0W', 'profile': '1hour', 'limit-uptime': '1h', 'uptime': '0s', 'bytes-in': '0', 'bytes-out': '0', 'packets-in': '0', 'packets-out': '0', 'dynamic': 'false', 'disabled': 'false', 'comment': '1 Hour : "30"'}]
names=[]
for i in my_list:

Comment: if i["profile"]=="1hour":
        names.append(i["name"])
print(f"Names:\n{names}")

Comment: this code returns output name "ARTRbD0W" in a list.
May be you mistook the spelling or something

Comment: I'm editing the answer

Comment: That is exactly how I want, it gave that output because the profile linked to that name is 1hour. On my side it still gives me the same error KeyError

Comment: Try copy pasting. If it works, then find the mistake (may be a spelling or may be an indentation is missing).
N.B: I've added ss also. It's working for me.

Comment: The error is because the first dictionary does not have the Key 'profile'.

Comment: for i in my_list:
    if "profile" in i:
        if i["profile"]=="1hour":
            names.append(i["name"])
use this.
Editted the answer also

Comment: If the answer is ok, then you can mark it as correct for others to find it also.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter the list of dictionaries you can use a list-comprehension:

```py
example = [
    {"name": "Jane", "gender": "female"},
    {"name": "Ben", "gender": "male"},
    {"name": "Kate", "gender": "female"},
    {"name": "James", "gender": "male"},
    {"name": "Lilly", "gender": "female"},
    {"name": "Sam", "gender": "male"},
    {"name": "Grace", "gender": "female"},
    {"name": "Dan", "gender": "male"},
]

females = [d["name"] for d in example if d["gender"] == "female"]
males = [d["name"] for d in example if d["gender"] == "male"]

print(f"{females=}")
print(f"{males=}")
```

Prints:

```py
females=['Jane', 'Kate', 'Lilly', 'Grace']
males=['Ben', 'James', 'Sam', 'Dan']
```

Comment: Will it work if the dictionary has more information, say age, marks, grade. Do I still use the same to filter the male and female?

Comment: @MichaelJoseph As long the dictionary has the required key (`"gender"`) it will work.